# How do I get Skype to stop re-marking old, seen voicemails/calls as unread?

Tags: windows, skype, notification-area

Skype has a tendency to mark certain calls, missed calls, and voicemails as unread, *after* I've already seen them. Usually this is after restarting; it will go back and mark one or two of the most recent ones unread just so it can have something to flash at me. But sometimes this happens even when it's just running normally. (The same message is seldom, if ever, marked unread more than once extra. But I can't be sure it never happens.)

I'm using 64-bit Windows 10, but the same thing happened on a previous install of 32-bit Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on Microsoft's side. About half of updates solve it, and the other half introduce it. After looking for a long time on Google, I found many outdated solutions. By using Skype Preview and Skype Desktop, the only thing I found is to mark an entire conversation as not read, but this is the exact opposite of what we need here.